# Custom title in PDF files when using ps2pdf

Tags: pdf

I convert .txt files to .ps files with enscript, OK!
After that I use "ps2pdf" to convert the .ps files to .pdf files. OK!

And I can see:

[image]

**Question**: What parameter do I have to use (with enscript or ps2pdf) to give the PDF's custom "$subject" name (I don't want "Enscript Output" title on the top of my PDF reader).

So this is not about the filenames, this is about the "$subject" that a PDF file has.

Comment: In English, it's called a *title*, not a *subject*. This should help when looking for documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angus is correct about the `%%Title:` comment controlling the title that the PDF will have.  But the easiest way to set the title with `enscript` is to use its `--title` option:

```
enscript --title 'My PDF title' foo.txt -o foo.ps
```

Comment: That is certainly easier :).

Comment: @cjm, What could I do if I have only the PDF file? I'd like to change its title which is different from its file name.

Answer (score 3):

At the beginning of each PS file, there are especially formatted comments with some important metadata. Among them, the title (take a look to the output of `head your-ps-file.ps`).

You need to change the `%%Title:` comment. One way could be to do it right when you convert it to PDF.

```
< psfile.ps sed '1,/^%%EndComments/ s/^%%Title:.*/%%Title: New Title/' | \
ps2pdf - pdffile.pdf
```